# How to dynamically import .js files in NodeJS with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, ts-node

> *tl;dr* I can import a `.mjs` file dynamically but not a `.js` one, even it has the same content.

When I run `node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./src/server.ts` for a project which imports an external file with [import() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) to run the ES6-style-exported function it contains as follows:

```js
// external.js
export default () => {
    return 'Hello World'
}
```

```js
// src/server.ts
// ...
export const applyFunction = async () => {
  const {default: transform} = await import(`${pathToFolder}/external.js`)
  const result = transform()
}
```

it throws an error:

```
(node:6132) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
[ERR] Unexpected token 'export'
```

I also receive that warning even if I have `"type": "module"` set in my `package.json`.

When I change the file extension to **`.mjs`**, it runs as it should: *no warning, no errors*

Is there any way I can have my external files with `.js` extension? Is it me or `ts-node` who should fix something?

P.S `"type": "module"` statement cannot be removed due to some other restrictions.